# 2D water shader in SFML

Tags: c++, glsl, sfml

I want to implement the algorithm for a 2D water surface described [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/the-water-effect-explained-r915) and [here](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_water.htm).

But instead of using two int arrays and calculating on the CPU I would like to use SFML's `sf::RenderTexture`'s (FBO's basically) and a GLSL shader to run everything on the GPU. I want to use SFML, because it's so simple and I have worked with it before, so I know my way around it a little.

I've made some good progress so far. I was able to set up 3 `sf::RenderTextures` and ping-pong between them correctly (because other than int array you can't read and write to the same `sf::RenderTexture` at the same time). I was also able to adapt the algorithm for the height field creation form being in the range -32.767 to 32.767 to the range 0 to 1 (or to be more precise -0.5 to 0.5 for the calculation). Also adding new ripples works to some extend. So up to this point you can actually see a little of waves going on.

Here comes my problem now: The waves disappear really, really fast and I don't even apply any damping yet. According to the algorithm the ripples are not stopping if there is no damping applied. It's even the other way around. If I apply "amplification" the waves look close to what you would expect them to look like (but they still disappear without any damping applied to them). My first thought was that this is, because I use float's in range 0 - 1 instead of integers, but I only see this being a problem if multiplication is used, but I only use addition and subtraction.

Here is my SFML C++ code :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 1000), "SFML works!");
    window.setFramerateLimit(12);

    sf::RenderTexture buffers[3];
    buffers[0].create(500, 500);
    buffers[1].create(500, 500);
    buffers[2].create(500, 500);
    sf::RenderTexture* firstBuffer = buffers;
    sf::RenderTexture* secondBuffer = &buffers[1];
    sf::RenderTexture* finalBuffer = &buffers[2];

    firstBuffer->clear(sf::Color(128, 128, 128));
    secondBuffer->clear(sf::Color(128, 128, 128));
    finalBuffer->clear(sf::Color(128, 128, 128));

    sf::Shader waterHeightmapShader;
    waterHeightmapShader.loadFromFile("waterHeightmapShader.glsl", sf::Shader::Fragment);

    sf::Sprite spritefirst;
    spritefirst.setPosition(0, 0);
    spritefirst.setTexture(firstBuffer->getTexture());

    sf::Sprite spritesecond;
    spritesecond.setPosition(500, 0);
    spritesecond.setTexture(secondBuffer->getTexture());

    sf::Sprite spritefinal;
    spritefinal.setPosition(0, 500);
    spritefinal.setTexture(finalBuffer->getTexture());

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();

            if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                window.close();
        }


        waterHeightmapShader.setParameter("mousePosition", sf::Vector2f(-1.f, -1.f));
        // if mouse button is pressed add new ripples
        if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
        {
            sf::Vector2i mousePosition = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
            if(mousePosition.x < 500 && mousePosition.y < 500)
            {
                sf::Vector2f mouse(mousePosition);

                mouse.x /= 500.f;
                mouse.y /= 500.f;

                mouse.y = 1 - mouse.y;


                std::cout << mouse.x << " " << mouse.y << std::endl;

                waterHeightmapShader.setParameter("mousePosition", mouse);
            }
        }


        waterHeightmapShader.setParameter("textureTwoFramesAgo", firstBuffer->getTexture());
        waterHeightmapShader.setParameter("textureOneFrameAgo", secondBuffer->getTexture());

        // create the heightmap
        secondBuffer->display();
        finalBuffer->clear(sf::Color(128, 128, 128));
        finalBuffer->draw(sf::Sprite(secondBuffer->getTexture()), &waterHeightmapShader);
        finalBuffer->display();


        spritefirst.setTexture(firstBuffer->getTexture());
        spritesecond.setTexture(secondBuffer->getTexture());
        spritefinal.setTexture(finalBuffer->getTexture());

        window.clear();
        window.draw(spritefirst);
        window.draw(spritesecond);
        window.draw(spritefinal);
        window.display();

        // swap the buffers around, first becomes second, second becomes third and third becomes first
        sf::RenderTexture* swapper = firstBuffer;
        firstBuffer = secondBuffer;
        secondBuffer = finalBuffer;
        finalBuffer = swapper;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is my GLSL shader code :

```
uniform sampler2D textureTwoFramesAgo;
uniform sampler2D textureOneFrameAgo;
uniform vec2 mousePosition;

const float textureSize = 500.0;
const float pixelSize = 1.0 / textureSize;

void main()
{
    // pixels position
    vec2 position = gl_TexCoord[0].st;

    vec4 finalColor = ((texture2D(textureOneFrameAgo, vec2(position.x - pixelSize, position.y)) +
                        texture2D(textureOneFrameAgo, vec2(position.x + pixelSize, position.y)) +
                        texture2D(textureOneFrameAgo, vec2(position.x, position.y + pixelSize)) +
                        texture2D(textureOneFrameAgo, vec2(position.x, position.y - pixelSize)) - 2.0) / 2) -
                       (texture2D(textureTwoFramesAgo, position) - 0.5);

    // damping
//    finalColor.rgb *= 1.9;  // <---- uncomment this for the "amplifiction" ie. to see the waves better
    finalColor.rgb += 0.5;

    // add new ripples
    if(mousePosition.x > 0.0)
    {
        if(distance(position, mousePosition) < pixelSize * 5)
        {
            finalColor = vec4(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0);
        }
    }

    gl_FragColor = finalColor;

}
```

Please remember that this is all just about the height field creation. There is no shading of the water yet.

Do you know why the waves disappear by them self without damping?

Comment: I'm sorry the algorithms are explained on those two pages: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/the-water-effect-explained-r915 http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_water.htm (I wasn't able to post more than two links, because I am new)

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

If I am reading the code correctly you sample the previous frame for the texture's colors/height and use four neighboring pixels/texels to determine the color/height of the current pixel.

As you are calculating (scaling) these neighbors you might run into missing the texel that contains the color/height you are looking for. It might not be the heighest texel, just one next to it a little bit lower causing the unexpected damping.

This is where you do **not** just use addition and subtraction:

```
const float pixelSize = 1.0 / textureSize;
```

By using this value you could just miss the texel you are looking for.

**EDIT**

Also: you are averaging the samples so the result will always be less than the maximum value of the samples. So instead of averaging you could select the maximum value. That might give weird results but also extra insight.

Comment: Wow first of all thanks for the crazy fast response! 
This actually makes a lot of sense! So how can I make sure that I access the neighbor texel?

Comment: You could make a test texture (so you'll know what the result should be after running a single frame) run a single frame and render the frame to a bitmap so you can examine the frame/bitmap values. By repeating this you should see what is going on. That is the only way I can imagine. A solution that might provide some insight could be to add extra samples. Also: you are averaging the samples so the result will always be less than the maximum value of the samples. So instead of averaging you could select the maximum value. That might give weird results but also extra insight.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did that. I uploaded the results here: http://imgur.com/KN2sUTh (it's scaled by two, no interpolation) Frame 3 and 5 do indeed look weird to me, so you were probably right. So what is the right way to get the neighbour texel in GLSL?

Comment: There is one thing you should do: do the calculation for a couple of pixels by hand using the bitmaps, see if the results are what you would expect from the algorithm. If they do, the algorithm is wrong. If they don't, the implementation of the algorithm might be wrong.

Comment: I did the calculation by hand on a grid paper. They look a little bit different from the one's on the bitmaps I posted, so i guess the implementation is wrong. I still think your first idea was probably right, that sometimes the step `1.0 / textureSize` doesn't get the neighbour texel and thus create the unexpected damping. But I don't know any other way and haven't found another way either... Could you tell me how this is done correctly?

Comment: Hmmm, imagine the texels to be really big. Now, where is (0, 0)? is it in the middle of the texel or at the top left of the texel? If it is at the top left, you'll probably get the average of the other texels that have a corner on (0, 0). It is easy to test by adding `0.5 * pixelSize` to `position.X` and `position.Y` (just a guess) See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Alright! I did a quick test and using `const float pixelSize = 1.0 / textureSize + 1.0 / textureSize * 0.5;` I get [this result](http://imgur.com/F7ioC7N). It still doesn't look right and the waves don't spread circular anymore, but at least they keep going now, while still doing a wavy motion. So I think I'm on the right track. But I'm not sure what's causing the error now...

Comment: no, now you adjusted the pixel size. You should adjust the offset of the sample coordinates.

Comment: Well, but the pixelSize is what I use as the offset. Or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong, pixels are still 1 / textureSize. Read this: http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/

Comment: Thanks for the interesting article! But right at the top it says that it's does not apply for OpenGL. I tried `position.xy += pixelSize * 0.5;` but i doesn't change anything...

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much for all the help! I really appreciate it! Would it be inappropriate to ask this question over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ because I feel like this is actually where it belongs.

Comment: I could be and you might find more people with knowledge about this.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some "Processing" codes which implements the same algorithm you've posted above, and its damping is correct, I hope you can get some points from it :

```
// codes begin

int Width = 800;
int Height = 600;
int FullSize = 0;
//int Spacing = 10;

int[] source, dest;
PImage bg;

void setup()
{
  // if you want to run these codes by "Processing"
  // please make a picture named "HelloWorld.png"
  bg = loadImage("HelloWorld.png");
  Width = bg.width;
  Height = bg.height;
  FullSize = Width * Height;
  size(Width, Height);
  source = new int[FullSize];
  dest = new int[FullSize];
  for (int i=0; i< FullSize; i++)
    source[i] = dest[i] = 0;
}

void draw()
{
  for (int i=Width; i< FullSize-Width; i++)
  {
    // check for bounds
    int xi = i % Width;
    if ((xi==0) || (xi==Width-1)) continue;

    dest[i] = (
    ((source[i-1]+
      source[i+1]+
      source[i-Width]+
      source[i+Width]) >>1) ) -dest[i];

    int dampFactor = 1000;
    dest[i] -= (dest[i] >> dampFactor); // Damping - Quick divde by 32 (5 bits)
  }

  //image(bg, 0, 0);
  loadPixels();
  for (int i=Width; i< FullSize-Width; i++)
  {
    // check for bounds
    int xi = i % Width;
    if ((xi==0) || (xi==Width-1)) continue;

    int xoffset = dest[i-1] - dest[i+1];
    int yoffset = dest[i-Width] - dest[i+Width];

    int offset = i+xoffset+yoffset*Width;
    if (offset>0 && offset<FullSize)
    {
      // TODO: make better map
      pixels[i] = bg.pixels[offset];
    }
  }
  //bg.updatePixels();
  updatePixels();

  //swap
  int[] temp = source;
  source = dest;
  dest = temp;
}

void mouseDragged() 
{
    if (mouseX > 0 && mouseX < Width && mouseY > 0 && mouseY < Height)
      source[mouseY*Width+mouseX] = (int)random(50, 100); 
}

void mousePressed()
{
   // TODO: make a area pulse value, like a radius circle
   if (mouseX > 0 && mouseX < Width && mouseY > 0 && mouseY < Height)
      source[mouseY*Width+mouseX] = (int)random(50, 100); 
}

// codes end
```